# Define multiple network forks in hardhat config

Tags: hardhat

I am testing a defi app (jest and ethers.js) that connects to both eth and polygon networks.

For running the tests I need 2 localhost nodes (eth and polygon) and after searching a bit online I found that hardhat can run localhost nodes.
I created an empty hardhat.config.js and managed to run the nodes as forks from goerli and mumbai networks. This is how the package.json running test scripts look like:

```
 "scripts": {
...
    "test": "npm run start-nodes ; sleep 5 ; nx test ; npm run kill-nodes",

    "start-eth-node" : "npx hardhat node --port 51234 --fork https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<infura-id> &",
    "start-polygon-node": "npx hardhat node --port 51235 --fork https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/<infura-id> &",
    "kill-eth-node" : "lsof -P | grep ':51234' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9",
    "kill-polygon-node": "lsof -P | grep ':51235' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9",
    "start-nodes": "npm run start-eth-node ; npm run start-polygon-node",
    "kill-nodes": "npm run kill-eth-node ; npm run kill-polygon-node",
```

This works well tests are running successful. But my question is if there is another way to not use all these configuration specific settings inside package.json but somehow configure it inside hardhat.config.js.

I tried to add new networks like this in hardhat.config.js:

```
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<infura-id>",
      forking: {
        url: "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<infura-id>",
      },
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: "test test test test test test test test test test test junk",
        count:5
      }
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: "https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/<infura-id>",
      forking:{
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/<infura-id>",
      },
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: "test test test test test test test test test test test junk",
        count:5
      }
    }
```

and then run this by using `hardhat node --port 51234 --network goerli &` and `hardhat node --port 51235 --network mumbai &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this repository https://github.com/mstable/mStable-contracts/blob/master/hardhat.config.ts

The key is to have a set of configurations `hardhat.config.ts`, then on your package.json indicate which configuration hardhat should use with the param `--config`.

Example

```
 "test:fork": "yarn hardhat --config hardhat-fork.config.ts test ./test-fork/**/*.spec.ts",
```